# NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

After I finished making this hangman game I decide to make a menu screen where it asks me if I wanted to play or not. So I put everything in the main() function and I'm getting an name error saying the variable text isn't defined. I know it has to do with global and private variables but I don't seem to be able to find the problem.

```
import pygame
import math
import random

pygame.init()

#display setup
window_width, window_height = 800, 500
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hangman Game!")

# button variables
RADIUS = 20
GAP = 15
letters = [] 
startx = round((window_width - (RADIUS * 2 + GAP) * 12) / 2)
starty = 400
A = 65

# give x and y positions for every letter button
for i in range(26):
    x = startx + (RADIUS * 2 + GAP) * (i % 13)
    y = starty + ((i // 13) * (GAP + RADIUS * 2))
    letters.append([x,y,chr(A+i), True])



#load images
images = []
for i in range(7):
    image = pygame.image.load("hangman" + str(i) + ".png")
    images.append(image)



#colors
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

WORD_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 40)


def draw():

    window.fill(WHITE)
    # draw title
    text = TITLE_FONT.render("hAnGmAn gAmE", 1, BLACK, (230,100,40))
    window.blit(text, (window_width/2 - text.get_width()/2, 20))
    # draw word
    display_word = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guessed:
            display_word += letter + " "
        else:
            display_word += "_ "


    text = WORD_FONT.render(display_word, 1, BLACK)

    window.blit(text, (400, 200))
    # draw buttons
    for letter in letters:

        # splits the x and y positions on the letter
        x, y, ltr, visible = letter

        # True? or False?
        if visible:
            pygame.draw.circle(window, BLACK, (x,y), RADIUS, 3)
            text = LETTER_FONT.render(ltr, 1, BLACK)
            window.blit(text, (x - text.get_width()/2, y - text.get_height()/2))


    window.blit(images[hangman_status], (150, 100))
    pygame.display.update()

# def render_text(text_to_display, text_x, text_y, font, color):
#     text = font.render(text_to_display, 1, color)
#     window.blit(text, (text_x, text_y))

def render_text(message, text_x, text_y):
    pygame.time.delay(1000)
    window.fill(WHITE)
    global text
    text = WORD_FONT.render(message, 1, BLACK)
    window.blit(text, (text_x, text_y))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(3000)

def main():
        # game variables
    global hangman_status 
    global words 
    global word 
    global guessed
    global LETTER_FONT
    global TITLE_FONT
    # game variables
    hangman_status = 0
    words = ["IDE", "REPLIT", "PYTHON", "PYGAME"]
    word = random.choice(words)
    guessed = [""]
        # fonts
    LETTER_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 40)

    TITLE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 50)
    # game loop setup
    FPS = 60
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    #game loop
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        

        # events
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            #what happens when the x is pressed
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            # what happens when the mouse button is pressed
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                m_x, m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for letter in letters:
                    x,y,ltr, visible = letter

                    # pythagorean theorem
                    # dis = c^2 and the things in the brackets adds the square of x and y distance of the mouse from the button
                    dis = math.sqrt((x - m_x)**2 + (y - m_y)**2)
                    if dis < RADIUS:
                        letter[3] = False
                        guessed.append(ltr)
                        if ltr not in word:
                            hangman_status += 1

        draw()
        
        won = True                
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in guessed:
                won = False
                break
        if won:
            render_text("YOU JUST WON CONGRATULATION", window_width/2 - text.get_width()/2, window_width/2 - text.get_width()/2)
            break
        if hangman_status == 6:
            render_text("YOU LOST TAKE AN L LOSER", window_width/2 - text.get_width()/2, window_width/2 - text.get_width()/2 )
            break

main()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global text` does *not* define `text` globally. It gets the globally defined variable `text`. Except you didn't ever define `text` in global scope. So, that's why nothing outside of `draw` and `render_text` can access that variable. You have to either define it globally, or put everything in a class and have it be a class attribute.

Comment: would it work if I define the variable text outside of the function and use
global text to use it inside of the function?

Comment: Yes, when I said "you have to either define it globally" that's what I meant.